# Grails: How to fetch a single item via named queries and additional criteria closure

Tags: grails, criteria

I am using Grails 2.4.3 and having trouble with named queries.

For example I have this

```
class Product {
   Customer customer
   ...
   static namedQueries = {
       byCustomer { Customer c ->
           eq('customer', c)
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

Now I can do

```
Product.byCustomer(customer).list()
```

I event can do

```
Product.byCustomer(customer).list(pagination + sorting ) {
    ... 
    gt('price', 23.5)
}
```

If I want a single object from gorm with criterias on it, I usually do

```
Product.createCriteria().get {
   ....
   eq('name', 'foo')
}
```

This will return the first matching Product with name == 'foo'

Now, what I want to do is this:

```
Product.byCustomer(customer).get {
    ...
    eq('type', 'bar')
}
```

This gives me:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server       
version for the right syntax to use near 'from product this_)' at line 1. Stacktrace follows:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'from product this_)' at line 1
```

I also tried this:

```
Product.byCustomer(customer) {
    ...
    eq('type', 'bar')
}.get()
```

which does also not work, since byCustomer(...) returns a collection.

What do I miss here ? I am really wondering cause all other methods seem to work, except .get() :

```
Product.byCustomer(customer).count {
    ...
    eq('type', 'bar')
}
```

(this is working)

I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

UPDATE:

As pointed out there are several options are given if you just want to query a fixed set of properties:

With where clause:

```
Product.byCustomer(customer).findWhere([type: 'bar'])
```

With another named query for "type"

```
Product.byCustomer(customer).byType('bar').get()
```

Problem: I have a dynamic set of criterias I want to add - and cannot create a named queries for all properties in my domain class.

UPDATE 2:

Example how I want to dynamically build by criteria, based on conditions:

```
Product p = Product.byCustomer(customer).get() {

        if (condition) {
            eq('a', params.int('bar'))
            gt('b', params.int('foo'))
            items {
                eq('c', 'baz')
            }
        } else {

            ...

        }
    }
```

### ANSWER

I think I found the way this will work for me. As I use Grails > 2.0 I can use 
[where-queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#whereQueries) which will return [DetachedCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#detachedCriteria)

DetachedCriteria has the missing get() method and I even can mix findWhere - like syntax with builder syntax - check this out:

```
Product.where { foo == '5' && bar > 8 }.get()
```

Or

```
Product.where { foo == '5' && bar > 8 }.build {
    items { 
        eq('baz', 5)
    }
}.get()
```

In both closures (where + build) I can dynamically add conditions.

Now the final part - reuse the namedQueries which already exists in the above Query

```
Product.where { foo == '5' && bar > 8 }.build {
    items { 
        eq('baz', 5)
    }

    Product.byCustomer(customer)
}.get()
```

Sweet! Unfortunately I cannot answer my own question yet :)

**UPDATE**

The last part is NOT working. How can I mix DetachedCriteria and named queries ?

Comment: `Product.byCustomer(customer).findWhere(type: 'bar')` should do.

Comment: But how can I add more criterias then? In this way I am loosing the criteria builder.

Comment: You can create a new named query for `type` and use that `Product.byCustomer(customer).byType('bar')`

Comment: What if I want to add dynamic criterias? I dont know the criterias in advance. I cannot create a named mapping for every property in my domain.

Comment: `Product.byCustomer(customer).findWhere(criteriaMap)`. then create the criteria map accordingly. It may contain `[type: 'bar', shape: 'foo']` or `[type: 'bar', shape: 'foo', color: 'baz']`.

Comment: How you are creating your dynamic query? Can you past it? This link(http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) can answer you question.

Comment: @user1690588 I added an example, I know the documentation of named queries in general. Does anyone know the reason why there is now method get like there is for count and list?

Comment: @dmahapatro how would I address relations or in general sub queries then?

Answer (score 1):

Since the result of a named query with a closure argument is a `java.util.ArrayList` you should be able to do

```
Product.byCustomer(customer){
    ...
    eq('type', 'bar')
}.getAt(0)
```

If the result is an empty list it will return `null`, otherwise it will return the first entry (in your case the only one). Tried with Grails 2.4.3.